# How to sort the indexes of an array in the fewest swaps

Tags: java

So say you are given an array with only letters A, B, and C.

A is larger than B, B is larger than C.

Now say you have to rearrange all the indexes in order, so that all A's appear before B, followed by C in the fewest possible swaps.

For example, [A,A,C,A,B] would require 2 swaps, first C and B, then A and B.

How would you create a program that would count the minimum amount of swaps required?

Comment: https://www.toptal.com/developers/sorting-algorithms

Comment: That's not as easy as it seems you have to implement sorting algorithms. Have you tried googling your problem before asking the question?

Comment: You start by researching sorting algorithms, then implement one or more with added instrumentation to count the swaps.  The number of swaps will depend on both the algorithm and the initial order. You'll find that for every algorithm, there will be initial orders for which it's very good, and initial orders for which it's bad.

Comment: Jyst FYI: This is a different question than how to sort a general list

Comment: @JimGarrison This isn'r really a question about sorting algorithms. Figuring out "minimum swaps" is appropriate for a decision tree

Answer (score 0):

You can user a counter variable to keep track of the swaps. Whenever the swap happens you can increment the counter variable. At the end what ever the the counter is that many swaps have occurred. You can also compare variables for equality and leave the swap and count happening.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is if you need to swap those letters or not.

If Yes - just count them with simple counter.

If No - then the easiest solution is to create copy of the array and swap elements there and use Yes option. But if you cannot create extra array it will be pretty harder from my point of view. You need to store somewhere which letter was "replaced" and probably a number of As in that array but that is just a guess.